# Execute servlet on startup of the application

Tags: java, servlets

I build a web application with JSPs and in my servlet I have:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

           init();        
           HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
           //more code...
    }
}
```

Till now my serlvet is called, when the JSP page calls it like `<a href="MyServlet..">`. What I want is whenever the application starts, the servlet to be executed as well. I could have a button in my 1st page like "START" and there to call the servlet.. But, can I avoid this?

Comment: What do you consider as "start"? Point when servlet container is started or point when user accesses application in the first time?

Comment: A Servlet is called when your will receive a HTTP Request, why do you want to call it automatically, as soon as application starts, any specific expectations?

Comment: Ok! I have some methods who check some things, so I want them to be checked when the application starts for the 1st time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whatever you want done on startup should be done by a class implementing `ServletContextListener`, so you should write such a class, for example:

```
public class MyContextListener 
           implements ServletContextListener{

  @Override
  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    //do stuff
  }

  @Override
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    //do stuff before web application is started
  }
}
```

Then you should declare it in web.xml:

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>
      com.whatever.MyContextListener 
   </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can configure it in Tomcat's web.xml (or corresponding configuration files in similar servers), like below using the tag `<load-on-startup>` :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyOwnServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>MyServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my point of view, a good way is to implement a Servlet Context Listener. It listens to application startup and shutdown.

```
public class YourListener implements javax.servlet.ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    }
}
```

And then, you configure the listener in your web.xml () or with the @WebServletContextListener annotation.

Comment: A ServletContextListener still needs a <load-on-startup>1 servlet to trigger.